# a lot of html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, 2d-games

I am working on html5 game based on canvas 2d. I have a problem with a lot of redraws(to make 30fps). I need to redraw a lot of objects.   Due to animation of units (like walls which lie above the units). I want to improve the perfomance of this and make alot of canvases for each object(about 200 canvases). Is it good solution? Or redraw 30 times per second alot of object on 1 canvas. Here is example:(base language russian) http://wpgame.cloudapp.net/Home/Game

[image]

Here are 2 units. First one above boxes second one below boxes. i use 1 canvas. To draw animation of units i need clear rectange area(and it influence to boxes) and i have to redraw boxes. I dont want to redraw boxes. and i think the solution is : make 2 canvases for and several canvases for boxes. And make redraw only on units canvases. But It can be slow.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very bad idea to have a lot of canvases. You should have 1 canvas, but redraw only the things you need to redraw. Common practise in javascript canvas based games (2d) is to have two arrays: 1 STATIC which will contain the level - walls, paths, ect, which will be drawn in the level initialization and another array - DYNAMIC which contains the things which move, like the player, enemies and so on.

This basically means that suddenly you don't need to redraw everything - just the things which move. This will improve the performance of your game significantly.

I suggest having a look at this: http://www.felinesoft.com/blog/index.php/2010/09/accelerated-game-programming-with-html5-and-canvas/

Comment: the problem is that i need to  hide units  below walls and some times need  units was above walls. i know only 2 ways. First: redraw walls and units every frame(due to animation of units) Second :Make canvas for every object sort them beetween each other. and redraw only unit canvas.

Comment: How about the following: If a unit is behind a wall REMOVE or HIDE it's texture. That way it will appear to be behind the wall. When it is infront of a wall, simply return it's texture. You can have a boolean variable and manipulate it's texture through it.

Comment: I added example image.  Here are 2 units. First one above boxes second one below boxes.  i use 1 canvas. To draw animation of units i need  clear rectange area(and it influence to boxes) and i have to redraw boxes. I dont want to redraw boxes. and i think the   solution is : make 2 canvases for and several canvases for boxes. And make redraw only on units canvases. But It can be slow.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. if that is the case I suggest to add the crates/walls which players can go arround to the DYNAMIC array (if you have one) and redraw them. The reason for that is that a call of a redraw function of a canvas will require much less resources than creating a new canvas just for this one object. So I suggest going with the redraw, since it will perform better.

Comment: I can't really give a lot more ideas about improving performance without knowing the architecture of the game. If you are not in a hurry and have time to look things up I suggest reading the rendering chapters from this book: Foundation Game Design with HTML5 and JavaScript. 

It offers the standard approaches for HTML5 game dev rendering which might help you.